Movie from late 80s or early 90s about troublesome teenage girl
I remember catching only a snippet of this movie but am hoping someone can identify it.
In the part I saw, a teenage girl gets caught up in a fight at school. I think someone deliberately provoked her and she fought back and of course she is the one who got into trouble. It might have been in art class that the fight happened because as the principal is leading her away, she slaps him on the back of his shirt with her hand covered in paint and leaves a green or blue handprint on his shirt.
In the next scene, she is getting into trouble with her step-father over the incidient. I also remember a wide shot of a very nice looking two-storey house in a pretty town or suburb. The way I understood it was that this girl lived with her mother and step-father in this posh house and they were quite wealthy, but the step-father did not like her so her life was not as picture perfect as it seemed. I could have just made this up to try to explain the movie to myself though!
I'm guessing the movie is from the late 80s or early 90s but I could be wrong. The girl in my mind looks a lot like Winona Ryder but I tried looking for movies with her from that time and nothing rings a bell.
I've been wondering about this film for over 20 years and just stumbled on this site. Would appreciate any suggestions of what it might be!

Sounds like "Terror in the Family" (1996)

"15 year old Deena Marten wants the same freedom every teenager craves. But when she can't have her way, her rebellious temperament erupts in violence. Her parents, Cynthia and Todd, fear her new boyfriend, Garret, 17, is the cause. Distraught, Cynthia turns to alcohol, and Todd escapes in his work. They're unaware their Boy Scout son Adam, 13, sips from a vodka bottle hidden in his bedroom. And the problems in this dysfunctional family continue to worsen."

The teenager Deena gets into a fight at school in the beginning and is a genuinely violent person.



